# Mobile site menu icon not clickable / doesn't expand

Tags: html, css, wordpress, navigation, mobile-website

When visiting our Wordpress website on a MOBILE device ([www.tradehounds.com](http://www.tradehounds.com)), I noticed that the menu icon in the top right corner is no longer clickable at all, and doesn't expand to show the menu tabs. Note: we do NOT have this same icon on our desktop site, as it's not needed due to desktop being larger and showing the entire menu.

I DON'T have the ability to directly edit the HTML of our theme in Wordpress, however I am able to edit the CSS, so a CSS solution would be most ideal.

Our theme was custom built many years ago. Also, I am not able to see an option to edit a "Mobile Menu" directly anywhere in our Wordpress account; I've gone through every section of Wordpress and no luck.

Other notes: We're on the most recent version of Wordpress. All plugins are up to date. On mobile, refreshing/closing tab/clearing cache does not solve the clickable menu problem.

We just need the mobile menu icon to be clickable.

Here is the CSS code for the entire menu, including the mobile specific code:

```
/*Header*/
    
    header .header-top .company-details {
        float: left;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0 16px;
        width: 100%;        
    }
    
    header .header-top .company-details li {
        float:right;
        font-size:13px;
    }
    
    header .header-top .company-details li:first-child {
        margin-right: 0;
        float: left;        
    }   

    header nav#top-menu-nav, 
    header .primary-navigation {
        float: none;
        top: 5px;
    }   

    header .navigation-wrapper {
        padding: <23></23>px 0;
    }
    
    header .navigation-wrapper .logo-img {
        max-width: 250px;
    }   
    
    header  .mobile-navigation {
        display:inline-block;
        position:relative;
        /* left:27px; */
        top:27px;
        float:right;
        float: right;
        margin-right: 16px;     
    }
    
    header  .mobile-navigation .navbar-toggle {
        margin:0;
         padding:0;
    }
    
    header  .mobile-navigation .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
        background-color: #000000;
        width: 34px;
        height: 34px;
        border-radius: 0;       
    }``
```

Many thanks in advance for any guidance!

Frankie

Answer (score 0):

Without having access to the innards of your Wordpress implementation, this is just a hunch but may be worth pursuing.

The thing that hinted that something may be wrong is your saying that you are on the latest version of Wordpress but that your theme was built many years ago. It's possible that that means you have a version of jquery loaded which your bootstrap implementation cannot handle.

I am seeing this error:

> Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery version 1.9.1
> or higher, but lower than version 3

and it is coming from bootstrap version 20190403

It looks as though you will need to get your theme to update to use a more recent bootstrap if that is the cause of the problem.